# Writing to channel in a loop

Tags: for-loop, netty

I have to send a lot of data to I client connected to my server in small blocks.

So, I have something like:

```
for(;;) { 
    messageEvent.getChannel().write("Hello World");
}
```

The problem is that, for some reason, client is receiving dirty data, like Netty buffer is not clear at each iteration, so we got something like "Hello WorldHello".

If I make a little change in my code putting a thread sleep everything works fine:

```
for(;;) { 
    messageEvent.getChannel().write("Hello World");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As MRAB said, if the server is sending multiple messages on a channel without indicating the end of each message, then client can not always read the messages correctly. By adding sleep time after writing a message, will not solve the root cause of the problem either.

To fix this problem, have to mark the end of each message in a way that other party can identify, if client and server both are using Netty, you can add LengthFieldPrepender and LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder before your json handlers.

```
String encodedMsg = new  Gson().toJson(
sendToClient,newTypeToken<ArrayList<CoordinateVO>>() {}.getType());
```

By default, Gson uses html escaping for content, sometime this will lead to wired encoding, you can disable this if required by using a Gson factory

```
final static GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping();

....

String encodedMsg = gsonBuilder.create().toJson(object);
```

Comment: How can i add LengthFieldPrepender and LengthFieldBasedFrameDecode parameters? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In neither case are you sending anything to indicate where one item ends and the next begins, or how long each item is.

In the second case the sleep is getting the channel time out and flush, so the client sees a 'break', which it interprets as the end of the item.

Comment: In both cases i do not use anything to indicate end.

Comment: In both cases the client reads as much input as it needs or is available at the time to create an item and then loops around for the next item. If the client waited for more than a second before reading the first item, then when it read its input it would see the data for both the first and second items sitting in its input and would think that was a single item.

Answer (score 0):

The client should never see this "dirty data". If thats really the case then its a bug. But to be hornest I can't think of anything that could lead to this in netty. As every Channel.write(..) event will be added to a queue which then get written to the client when possible. So every data that is passed in the write(..) method will just get written. There is no "concat" of the data.

Do you maybe have some custom Encoder in the pipeline that buffers the data before sending it to the client ?

It would also help if you could show the complete code that gives this behavoir so we see what handlers are in the pipeline etc.

Comment: I do not use custom Encoder, the real code is :   for (CoordinateVO coordinate : coordinates) {
   sendToClient.add(coordinate);
   if (sendToClient.size() == 2) {

    String resultSerialized = new Gson().toJson(sendToClient,new TypeToken<ArrayList<CoordinateVO>>() {}.getType());

    logger.info("Sending : " + resultSerialized);
    ChannelBuffer channelBuffer = ChannelBuffers.buffer(resultSerialized.getBytes().length);
    channelBuffer.writeBytes(resultSerialized.getBytes());
    e.getChannel().write(channelBuffer);
    
    
    sendToClient.clear();
   }
  }